# My hamburguer icon in action bar doesn't open the drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have a problem with my hamburguer icon, if I touch don't open the drawer.
My drawer only works with the action bar layout, but I need it transparent and only can make with the toolbar, I'm brazilian and sorry for the errors of english

img :
[img of the toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fgrz.png)

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        Window window = this.getWindow();

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_Layout, new Fragment_Inicio());
        fragmentTransaction.disallowAddToBackStack();
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view_inthebox);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Helper h = new Helper();
        ImageButton callflex = findViewById(R.id.nav_logo);
        h.Abrir_link_externo_botao(callflex,"https://www.callflex.com.br", this);
        ImageButton linkedin = findViewById(R.id.nav_linkedin);
        h.Abrir_link_externo_botao(linkedin,"https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/949222/", this);
        ImageButton instagram = findViewById(R.id.nav_instagram);
        h.Abrir_link_externo_botao(instagram,"https://www.instagram.com/callflexbr/", this);
        ImageButton facebook = findViewById(R.id.nav_facebook);
        h.Abrir_link_externo_botao(facebook,"https://www.facebook.com/callflex/", this);
        ImageButton youtube = findViewById(R.id.nav_youtube);
        h.Abrir_link_externo_botao(youtube,"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyMBD5Pcu6nHUlDij_N-iRw", this);
    }
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Can someone help me? I need this hamburguer icon work.

Comment: What's that at the end of your question body? Please do not spam system to post your question on StackOverflow.

Comment: xd should be caps otherwise it doesn't mean anything

Comment: Looking at your image it looks like your `content_main` overlaps the `Toolbar` and is stealing the clicks from it. Try putting the `<include>` inside the `RelativeLayout` and set `android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the layout was overlapping the status bar, as said in the comment of darwind, I arranged by inverting and putting the include in the right place.